A script that executes a command in an already running terminal session on windows 10?
I run a server and want to execute a command in the console automatically before I turn off the PC.
I just need a script.
Is this possible without downloading another program?
I would then add the script to shutdown scripts in local group policy editor...
Please help me im a beginner...

What research have you done and what have you tried so far?

@music2myear I looked online for solutions and tried to create scripts, e.g. open /path/to/file .stb (command)

I think I understand what you want to do, and it is something I wanted to and after lots of things, I found out the hard way that it is no longer possible to do this in Windows 10 and up.
While it is still technically possible to get a program to run at log off/shutdown, Windows will run your script/program, but immediately after it started, the computer is shutdown anyway, and your script is just terminated mid-way its execution.
The only way to get this to work reliably is to create a script that does whatever you want it to do, and end the script with the shutdown command.
The hard part is that you can't use the normal way of turning off your computer anymore. I ended up using Classic Start, which allows me to choose what the turn off action is, and changed this from turning off the computer, to putting it in stand by. If I then accidentally use it, I can just turn it back on.
Later on, I used GPO to disable the ability to shut down from the start menu altogether, and I pinned my script right next to the start menu which seems to work well for not accidentally turning it off anyway.
As for the power button, you can just configure what the power button does from the Energy Management settings.
